# $V$ a vector bundle rank $n$ over scheme. Is there algebraic analogue to construct a map of $V\to Gr_n$ where $Gr_n$ is grassmanian n-plane bundle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $V$ be a vector bundle rank $n$ over a scheme $X$.

In topology over paracompact space $X$, there is a map $V\to Gr_n(R^\infty)$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is there algebraic geometric analogue to construct a map of $V\to Gr_n$ where $Gr_n$ is grassmanian n-plane bundle over some scheme say $X$? It seems that I no longer have a canonical $R^\infty$ to embed the fiber linearly but instead $O_X^\infty$ which may not allow embedding of fibers.

Comment: If you twist the bundle sufficiently so that there are 'enough' sections, then this can be done.

Comment: There is a relatively common method of creating the Grassmanian bundle of $r$-dimensional sub-bundles of a fixed vector bundle $E$ on a scheme $X$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_bundle) or Fulton's Intersection Theory for instance). I'm not sure about your general goal, though - what would you want to have happen for $O(-1)$ on projective space, for instance?

Comment: @KReiser Say $P^2$ for simplicity. $O(-1)$ is 3 dimensional over $C$. So I would hope there is a linear "fiberwise embedding" $O(-1)\to \prod^3 C^3$ where I need to take partition of unity on $P^2$ but there is no analogue of this on $P^2$ in zariski sense. I guess my question does not make too much sense here.